FilePicker on MAUI App using MacCatalyst does not give FullPath
When debugging MAUI applicaion on Mac using MacCatalyst, whenever I try to get the FullPath of a file selected, I get the temporary file location (/var/folders/v2/<long-random-string/T/-inbox/text.txt), and not the actual physical path (Users//Documents/text.txt).
I tried updating the Entitlements.plist as mentioned here, and giving the app full disk access to no avail.

From the docs Pick multiple files:

The FullPath property doesn't always return the physical path to the
file. To get the file, use the OpenReadAsync method.


Thank you, is there way to gurantee a physical path is returned? I would like to write to the original file.

@Tyche3 Probably not, but you can use await fileResult.OpenReadAsync(); to get the file.
